# Eclipse + PyDev define function based on function call

Tags: python, eclipse, templates, pydev, code-completion

I have noticed a particular feature in Visual Studio and I am wondering if this feature is also available in Eclipse + PyDev.

In Visual Studio, if one were to type a function call and that particular function does not already exist, VS would show a code error and give an option to generate a new empty function matching the signature provided in the function call.

In other words, same I am working in a particular Python function or class and I realize I need a new function to process some string.  In my current function I type `processString(myString)`, which returns an error because the processString function does not currently exist.  Is there some way to then click on the `processString` function call and create a new block in my module:

```
def processString(myString):
    pass
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Sounds like a feature request.  http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=85796&atid=577332

Comment: With Java in Eclipse, Ctrl-1 generates a new empty method, when a method is invoked before it is defined. Does that work with PyDev?

Comment: It is *not* possible to mark a comment as an answer. But I strongly encourage you to move that UPDATE into an answer of your own, and then accept it... This sounds like something that could be helpful to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Eric Wilson.

If I type the function call `processString(myString)` then hit 'CTRL+1' the code completion/template window appears offering me the option to create a new class, method, assign to a field, or assign to a variable.

This was exactly what I was looking for.